# vi: is there a way to manipulate regex matches?

Tags: vim

I have a file with the following line:

```
img width="240" height="120"
```

I want to scale the width and height by the same amount so

```
:%s/width="\\(.*\\)" height="\\(.*\\)"/width="2*\\1" height="2*\\2"/g
```

produces

```
img width="2*240" height="2*120"
```

is there anyway to make vi actually compute `2*240=480` and put `480` in the result.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I can get something close to what you ask with

```
:s/\(\d\+\)/\=submatch(1)*2/gc
```

But I would use an external filter.

Answer (score 1):

I would typically use an external filter for that sort of thing:

```
:%!perl -pe 's/width="(\d*)"/sprintf "width=\"\%d\"", 2 * $1/e'
```

Note that there is an additional escape there that would not appear when running perl directly.  You must escape the % sign or vim will expand it to the current filename.

But you might try:

```
:help sub-replace-expression
```

if you don't want to use an external filter.